# Out of memory Exception in ListView and pagerview together

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, out-of-memory, fragmentstatepageradapter

I create an application with `ListView` and `ViewPager`.
I used `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as pageradapter.

when click on item in list, open an `pagefragment` to load detail data.
I monitor memory allocated in android studio monitor, when click on item 
in list view memory is allocated.

My problem is here: 
when back from pager to list,and click on item, memory is allocated again.
if I done this steps, an OutOfMemory is thrown.
I use

> android:largeHeap="true"

But does not work for me.
Some piece of my code:

listview onItemClickListener:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //peace of code that create launch new fragment with swipe view inside

                FragmentPager fragmentPager = new FragmentPager();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("CURRENT_POSITION", position);

                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("DATA_LIST", data);

                fragmentPager.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container, fragmentPager, "swipe_view_fragment");
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();

            }
        });
```

My FragmentPager:

```
public class FragmentPager extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

        if(v==null)
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, container, false);
        if(mViewPager==null)
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager_view);

        currentPosition = getArguments().getInt("CURRENT_POSITION");

        data = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("DATA_LIST");


        FragmentItemPagerAdapter fragmentItemPagerAdapter = new FragmentItemPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), data,this.getActivity());
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(fragmentItemPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition);
        fragmentItemPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return v;
    }
}
```

and my FragmentItemPagerAdapter:

```
public class FragmentItemPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
@Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        container.removeView(container);
        /*if (position >= getCount()) {
            container.removeAllViews();
            FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
            trans.remove((Fragment) object);
            trans.commit();
        }*/

    }

}
```

Comment: by pagerView you mean ViewPager? I really recommend to use RecyclerView in this case.

Comment: And also this not issue with ViewPager or ListView you should give more details what's going on. Also setting large heap not recommend by google.

Comment: I might be wrong here but, you don't need to create the pager again and again. Use the 'FragmentManager.findFragmentById' of 'FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag' to check if the fragment already exists. If it does not, then create a new instance. As for the memory consumption, whats is the layout doing? Does it display big imagery?

Comment: @GPuschka: my views are text based.

Comment: @Amir: how to set large heap?

Comment: @MiladAlizadeh In fact you dont need to set large heap. your problem due to non proper allocation of resources so set large heap doesnt solve anythings.

Comment: @Amir: i comment every line of my fragment, just show empty fragment without any object instantiation, but exception is remained.

Comment: can you put whole source in gitHub?

Comment: i am newbie in android,and just use a sample to do this,my code is maybe wrong. is any better solution?

Comment: Also FragmentItemPagerAdapter seems to be buggy.

Comment: I dont know what exact logic you want to implement !

Comment: i have a big list(for exp: 4000 item in list) and a viewpager to swipe between pages, user (specific user,not general user) need to load list once, and work with it in during a week, then back to organization and load new list.

Comment: Can you please post model for which you have passed list of data?

Comment: i have list of header in list view and show some of them,then pass header to viewpager, show all of header fields and populate detail items based on. (like a master detail view)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

put in Mainfest--->

```
<application
        android:largeHeap="true"
    >
.....
   </application>
```

may it will help

Answer (score 0):

May be your readFromParcel and writeToParcel methods doesn't match and if you can avoid to pass whole list of array to the fragment.